# How can i listen a button on widget

Tags: android, button, widget, click

First of all, i am sory because of my english is bad and 
i am new in android.İ have a problem,i want to a calculator  widget on android but 
my code not  work.
i firstly apply button click only one button which idname  is buttun1.
that my code please help me.
thanks.

```
package widgetcalculator;
import com.example.widgetcalculator.R;,

public class Calculator extends AppWidgetProvider {

    RemoteViews rmViews; 
 ComponentName cmName; 
 AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
 public static String WIDGET_BUTTON = "com.example.widgetcalculator.button1";
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);


    rmViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);




    appWidgetManager = this.appWidgetManager;



    Intent intent = new Intent(WIDGET_BUTTON);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    rmViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent );



}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    RemoteViews rmViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
    if (WIDGET_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //your code here
        rmViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "1");

        cmName = new ComponentName(context, Calculator.class); 
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(cmName, rmViews);
            }

}

}
```

and my mainfest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.widgetcalculator"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <receiver android:name=".Calculator" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.example.widgetcalculator.button1" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />,

        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>


</application>
```

and my layout/ main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttontop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoncik"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoncarp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonnokta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please refer to the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking a good question. Avoid posting pages of code as people do not want to read through it all, post where you think the problem is occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
//action for buttons
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_PLAY_PAUSE = "btn_play_pause";
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_STOP = "btn_stop";
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_PREV_TRACK = "btn_prev_track";
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_NEXT_TRACK = "btn_next_track";
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_MUTE = "btn_mute";
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_VOL_UP = "btn_vol_up";
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_VOL_DOWN = "btn_vol_down";
public static final String ACTION_WIDGET_EXPAND_WIDGET = "btn_transparent_activity";
// <Action, ButtonId>
private static final HashMap<String, Integer> CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// <Actions>
private static final ArrayList<String> ACTIONS = new ArrayList<String>();

static {
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_PLAY_PAUSE, R.id.btn_media_play_pause);
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_STOP, R.id.btn_media_stop);
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_PREV_TRACK, R.id.btn_media_previous);
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_NEXT_TRACK, R.id.btn_media_next);
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_MUTE, R.id.btn_media_mute);
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_VOL_UP, R.id.btn_media_vol_up);
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_VOL_DOWN, R.id.btn_media_vol_down);
    CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.put(ACTION_WIDGET_EXPAND_WIDGET, R.id.btn_show_activity);
    // Fill action list
    ACTIONS.addAll(CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.keySet());
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    Intent activeIntent;
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent;
    int mapSize = CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.size();
    // Fill btn id list
    ArrayList<Integer> btnIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    btnIds.addAll(CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.values());
    // Set button listeners
    for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) {
        activeIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        activeIntent.setAction(ACTIONS.get(i));
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activeIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(btnIds.get(i), actionPendingIntent);
    }
    //Update
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AppControllerService.class));
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTIONS.contains(action)) {
        int btnId = CLICK_INTENT_ACTIONS_MAP.get(action);
        switch (btnId) {
            case R.id.btn_media_play_pause:
            case R.id.btn_media_stop:
            case R.id.btn_media_previous:
            case R.id.btn_media_next:
            case R.id.btn_media_mute:
            case R.id.btn_media_vol_up:
            case R.id.btn_media_vol_down:
                break;
            case R.id.btn_show_activity:
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityMain.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
}
```

}